# LinkedList: How to assign the current node to the node after it? When removing current node

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have to remove the current node in a linked list, which cursor is assigned to so cursor represents my current node. After removing the current node or cursor, the cursor should be assigned to the node after the node that was just removed. I've removed the node, but i don't understand how to assign the cursor to the node after it.

Edit: I want to use cursor as a reference to my current node, so i want to assign or set cursor to node 3. So once i remove node 2 and set node 1's link to node 3, cursor should be assigned to node 3 and node 3 would be my current node which cursor represents.

```
        Cursor                                                   Cursor
  [1] -> [2] -> [3]               Result should be this:   [1] -> [3]
          |
       Removing
```

Here's what i've done:
The for loop moves through the list and it stops just before cursor so it gets the node before cursor which is prevCursor. Then i set prevCursor's link to the node after the removed node linking the node before cursor to the node after the removed node.

```
public boolean removeCurrentNode()
{
    AirportNode prevCursor = null;

    if(cursor != null)
    {
        for(prevCursor = head; prevCursor != cursor; prevCursor = prevCursor.getNext())
        {

        }


        prevCursor.setNext(prevCursor.getNext().getNext());

    }
```

Comment: check wikipedia->LinkedList or google it.

Comment: You usually have to use a temporary variable to do something like this.  `temp = cursor.getNext(); delete(cursor); cursor = temp;`.  If I understand correctly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mybirthname the question seem to be "I have function that returns value I need (next node), how to to assign result to a variable" (like `cursor = prevCursor.getNext();`) - nothing really to do with linked list.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list check remove element of linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are already at node 2 in this list : 1 --> 2--> 3--> null

If 'cursor' points to node 2 at this time and you want to delete node 2, then

Copy the next element (node 3) to 'cursor' position.

```
cursor.data = cursor.next == null ? null : cursor.next.data
```

Point 'cursor' next to next of next

```
if(cursor.next != null) {
     cursor.next = cursor.next.next
}
```

Comment: There is a problem that's about deleting an element from singly linked list given access to only the node to be deleted - it is based on that concept.

Comment: Im not trying to get the contents of node 3 into cursor, i want to set the cursor node to node 3 so i can use cursor as a reference to node 3.

Comment: Nvm i got it, you're right, i was confused with the wrong idea been sitting here too long lol... yea it's just as u say point cursor to the next of next, so cursor = cursor.link